# How to convert time from UTC to say "Pacific/Easter"?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am getting time from server as "19:30" but it needs to be converted to "Pacific/Easter time zone.

I have tried things like

```
 let t = "19:30:00";
let utc = moment.utc(t);
let z = moment(utc).utcOffset(-300).format('HH:mm');
```

But I am going wrong somewhere.

I have seen in my dev app version that it is being converted to 14:30 which is like -5:00 hours.

So, how do I get similar result for this?

Here's something else that I tried

```
let t = "19:30:00"; 
let tt = moment.tz(t, "UTC");
let nt = tt.clone().tz("Pacific/Easter");
```

and I am getting nt as "19:30:00" also. so , it's not converting at all

this is the one that seems to be working.
but it's not showing the correct result

```
let t = "19:30:00";
let utc = moment.utc(t, 'HH:mm:ss');
let z = utc.tz('Pacific/Easter').format('HH:mm');
console.log(z);
```

it should show the result as 19:30 -5 hours which should be 14:30,
but it shows the result as 13:30. so, anyone knows why this is happening??

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) function from moment-timezone.

Since your input (`19:30:00`) is not in ISO 8601/RFC 2822 recognized format you have to [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) it using [`moment.utc(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) passing `'HH:mm:ss'` as  second parameter.

Then you can convert your moment object to given timezone using [`tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/).

Please note that, even if you are providing only time, you are creating a moment object that includes date. As [Default](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/defaults/) section of the docs states:

> You can create a moment object specifying only some of the units, and the rest will be defaulted to the current day, month or year, or 0 for hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

`'Pacific/Easter'` uses [Daylight Saving Time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) (see full info [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/chile/easter-island)) so the conversion depends on date and DST.

If you want to use fixed offset (no DST), you can use [`utcOffset()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/):

> Setting the UTC offset by supplying minutes. Note that once you set an offset, it's fixed and won't change on its own (i.e there are no DST rules).
>
> If the input is less than `16` and greater than `-16`, it will interpret your input as hours instead.

Here a live sample:

```js
let t = "19:30:00";
let utc = moment.utc(t, 'HH:mm:ss');
let z = utc.tz('Pacific/Easter').format('HH:mm');
console.log(z);

// DST
console.log( moment.utc('2018-09-01 19:30:00').tz('Pacific/Easter').format('HH:mm') );
// No DST
console.log( moment.utc('2018-06-01 19:30:00').tz('Pacific/Easter').format('HH:mm') );
// Fixed offset
console.log( moment.utc('19:30:00', 'HH:mm:ss').utcOffset(-5).format('HH:mm') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.17/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok, that seems to be working. But in the dev app which is also converting the same time shows the time as 14:30 and this is showing the time as 13:30 after conversion.

Comment: I mean the result should be -5 hours from what we give. so, 19:30 after conversion should show up as 14:30. how to make that happen?

Comment: Ok, I understand, I'm on mobile, I'll try to improve my aswer as soon as I get access to my laptop.

Comment: by the way, is there a way to do
utcOffset('Pacific/Easter') instead of -5 ?? 
or maybe a way to find if we should d0 -5 or add +10 based on the timezone??
say we have some other timezone and it puts in that value in those brackets
like utcOffset(x) where x is the value that should be added or subtracted based on timezone

Comment: No there is no `utcOffset('Pacific/Easter')`, you can only use `tz()` that is designed to take DST changes in account. You can use something like `moment().tz('Pacific/Easter').utcOffset()` to get the current UTC offset for a given zone (From [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/): _Get the UTC offset in minutes_).

Comment: ok thanks. this seems to be a very tricky thing. times and time zones i.e.

Answer (score 1):

You need moment-timezone to get this working.

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
```

Comment: no. this didnt help. here's what I did. 
let t = "19:30:00";
let tt = moment.tz(t, "UTC");
let nt = tt.clone().tz("Pacific/Easter");

and I am getting nt as "19:30:00" also. so , it's not converting at all